# OpenCV 3.0 installation on Windows with Python bindings for Python 3.2.5

Tags: python, opencv

I need to install the Python cv2 library in Python 3.2.5. I am trying to get a correct solution file for this using CMake 2.8.11.2. Unfortunately, I am not able to get the Python bindings included. BUILD_opencv_python3 is switched on in the CMake GUI and  BUILD_opencv_python2 is switched off, but if I run configure, I get

> Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "3.2.5", but
> required is at least "3.4"
>
> Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (found
> suitable version "3.2.5", minimum required is "3.2")

and then

> Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec
> cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect
> cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java **python3** viz

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Set PYTHON_EXECUTABLE to the executable python file. Use cmake graphical interface is an easy way to do that.

Comment: Python 3.2 is ancient. Any reason why wou have to use this?

Comment: My employer is not ready to upgrade. I am not in a position to make decisions about this.